# Is it possible to uninstall one android application from other application?

Tags: android, android-intent

Suppose there are two different Android apps: A and B.

App A is a system admin. Is there any way for it to uninstall app B or make it non-functional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you need to use `Intent.ACTION_DELETE`  have a look at following code,

```
Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:com.mypackgage");  
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE,packageUri);  
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

when you run the above code, it will ask for uninstall application as follows, image

> [image]

Comment: When the user presses cancel here, is it possible to detect it and prompt user again to uninstall??

Comment: you may have to try your self.

Answer (score 1):

try below code for uninstall apk...

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.example.uninstall"); // replace with your package name
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
uninstallIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the below code snippet you can uninstall an installed application on your ANDROID phone.It redirected you to the uninstall confirmation...

> Create an intent object with an action and data as the package name
>   and start with the ACTION_DELETE.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.pack.Applicationname"));
startActivity(intent);
```