# Uninstall other apps from my own

Tags: android, permissions, uninstallation

I would like to know if it is possible to uninstall other apps from my own app. Does the Android OS allow us to do this?

I have gone through [a similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493032/is-it-possible-to-uninstall-one-android-application-from-other-application).

But in the above question, app A is a system admin. In my case, my app is an ordinary application. What is the difference between a system admin application and a regular one?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same code mention in the other question in any normal application. Copying the code again:

```
Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:com.mypackgage");  
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE,packageUri);  
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Please try this code in your app.